# Set a custom page "site is unavailable" in Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to define a custom HTML page or redirect to another site when the site is offline, instead of having the generic [Site unavailable page](http://www.azurewebsites.net/SiteUnavailable.htm) ?

I see 2 reasons for a site to be offline :

- The administrator stopped it in the Azure portal
- OR : The site has reached its resources quota (for example in "Free" or "Shared" mode).

For the first I <strike>understand</strike> accept that possibilities are limited.
But for the second, I'd like to set a specific message for my users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/) in failover mode, but this only works for Cloud Services, not websites.  There are other DNS service providers like DynDNS that offer similar functionality.

This, of course, won't work in FREE mode since you can't have a custom domain anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answer viperguynaz. I'm discovering the Azure Traffic Manager with your post. This solution seems to work with long offline durations, but don't seem appropriate for specific quota overhead like CPU Time in Azure, because according to [this MSDN page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/), (figure 8), the check interval of the traffic manager and the DNS TTL can be bigger than the Azure quota reset (5 min for CPU Time). Do you agree or did I miss something ?

Comment: concur - and that's going to be the case for most any similar service.

Comment: As the offline event is raised by MS, I expected a smart Azure specific solution :/

Comment: Is there a solution out now?

Comment: Azure Traffic Manager now works with websites and is a good solution.